# Colors and corresponding numbers

Tags: combinatorics

> The 10 colors Green, Blue, Violet, Red, Orange, Yellow,  Cyan, Magenta, Fuchsia, Brown are associated to each of the numbers 1, 2,…, 10 but we don’t know which color corresponds to each number. In a large box there are infinite sealed envelopes, each containing one card of the above colors. 
>   Our target is to find which number corresponds to each color.
>   There is a keypad with the 10 numbers outside this box. Each time I type a sequence of 5 numbers (10 is considered as ONE number), and 5 envelopes come out of the box (but not in the order I typed the numbers). 
>   We can open the envelopes and see the colors but we will still not know which is which. We can repeat this process only 3 times. Is it possible to determine the correspondence of colors with the numbers? What combinations of numbers must we use each of the 3 times?

Let's say we first type 11223. Then we get 5 envelopes, of which, 2 + 2 will have the same color of cards. So now we know the color that corresponds to number 3 and also we know that 1 & 2 correspond to two other colors (that we also know - but we don't know which is which).

We repeat the same process with 44556. Again we know 6, and 4 & 5.
In our last turn, we type 1, 4, 7, 8, 9. 
It the 5 envelopes, we will see 2 of the colors we have already seen in the first two draws and we will now know 1, 4 and 7 & 8 & 9, but not which is which. We will also know number 10.

We can also do 11223, 14456, 57789 but I am still missing one number :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this works:

```
11234 implies (1)(234)
25567 implies (1)(2)(34)(5)(67)
36889 implies (1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)
and the only color you haven't seen is (10)
```

Comment: EthanBolker you are a genius! Thank you very much!

Comment: @JuanManuelPrada You're welcome. No genius - just suspecting that doubling two  numbers in a query would waste a chance to extract a little more information.